# objective c method call from javascript file

Tags: objective-c, ios

i would like to know how to call an objective c method from javascript. for example i have a javascript function defined in my myFile.js like this :

```
function() {
alert('test');
....          // How i can an objective c function here ???
}
```

i have also a UIWebView :

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
....
// what to do here ?????? 
}
```

thanks for your answer

Comment: There are many question in SO like you ask for. please search for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the location to something you recognize and check if the request.URL matches that.

```
function nav(f){
 location.href = "methodCall";
}

-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if([request.URL.relativeString isEqualToString:@"methodCall"]){
        //call method here
        return false; //so it doesn't navigate anywhere
    }
    return true; //if you want every other link to work normally.
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this but I imagine it will work, though the URL returned by request.URL.relativeString may be a bit different, so just set a breakpoint there and see what it is.